# ExtJS 6 - Date Time Picker's numberfield not editable

Tags: datetime, extjs, datepicker, datetimepicker, extjs6

I have tried to extend existing ExtJS6 date picker for date time picker.
I used `numberfield` in the date picker as the selection for time.
However, the number field is not editable. Not only that, the spinner in `numberfield` once click the date picker is gone.

Can someone enlighten me where did I got it wrong ?
Why the `numberfield` is not editable ?

Code in Fiddle.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tc3

Comment: Have you searched for prior art? I have seen a similar (but fully working) component somewhere on the net. Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: What I have found was for ExtJS-4, which is work perfectly.
Tried with ExtJS-4 also work flawlessly, but once ported to ExtJS-6 it does not work any more, of course with little change to cope with existing ExtJS-6.

Found another but it is a slider instead of input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ownerCt and ownerLayout properties on your buttons in the beforeRender method.

```
me.minuteBtn = new _$Number({
    ownerCt: me,
    ownerLayout: me.getComponentLayout(),
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 59,
    step: 1,
    width: 68
});
```